# Word Documents in Library Erroring and Unable to Overwrite

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions, word

I have a document library and a number of times I have experienced an issue where, upon trying to open a document in Word for editing, it throws an error

> The file filename.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.
>
> Details:
>
> Unspecified error
>
> Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line: 2, Column: 0

I click "OK" and then it prompts:

> Word found unreadable content in "filename.docx". Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click "Yes".

So I click "Yes" and the document is recovered.

I then try to save and overwrite the original, but when I do I get the error:

> filename.docx
>
> The file name is not valid.

However if I save with a new filename it works. This however is not a favoured solution as there are workflows running on the library items.

All documents in the library are effectively the same and there doesn't seem to be any correlation between the ones that have failed.

I am logged in as site collection administrator and have full control permissions for the site, library and library items.

In addition, but perhaps a separate issue, I am unable to open the library in Windows Explorer. It throws the error

> \mywebapp\DavWWWRoot\sites\mysite\mydoclibrary is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> The parameter is incorrect.

I DO have access permissions and can access other libraries this way.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it`s a MS Word problem similar to this one [here](http://help.wugnet.com/office/open-docx-file-content-error-ftopict1081932.html).
Their solution was:

1. make a backup copy of the corrupt file
2. right-click the file and selected 'Save As' on the menu (I'm using Win XP with Word 2007 installed, I hope you have the same option)
3. A save as dialog box appears
4. Enter a new file name and select Word 97-2003 as the file type.
5. Click Save

If it is indeed a corrupt file, why would you want to save it again in your library?

Comment: As I said in my original post, if I save it under a new filename that works but as there are workflows running on the library item, that is not a realistic option. I don't want to save the corrupt version - I want to overwrite it.

Comment: Are the Document Check-In/Check-Out /Versioning options enabled?

Comment: Versioning=Major versions
Checkout=Not required.
Makes no difference if I change the check out value.